# Verbo para "hacer más complejo algo"

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Me gustaría conocer el verbo para **hacer más complejo algo**, del mismo modo que **hacer algo más complicado** tiene el verbo *complicar*. Es curioso porque **acomplejar** si es un verbo, pero obviamente no tiene el significado que estoy buscando.

Comment: Por favor, incluye una frase con _____ donde iría la palabra que buscas, para mostrar el contexto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El verbo que estás buscando es ***complejizar***. El mismo no se encuentra en el Diccionario de la Lengua Española de la RAE y al menos Fundéu [desaconseja su uso](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/complicar-mejor-que-complejizar/), ya que en la práctica significa lo mismo que *complicar*. (Por supuesto, que una palabra no esté en el DLE no significa que no exista; en particular *complejizar*, acuñada de manera espontánea, es usada en los medios y en escritos técnicos.)

*Complicado* y *complejo* son sinónimos pero no significan exactamente lo mismo en todas sus acepciones. Por la forma en que se utiliza, sin embargo, *complejizar* suele ser prácticamente lo mismo que *complicar*.

*Acomplejar* es diferente porque no deriva del adjetivo *complejo*, sino del sustantivo; *complejo* (m.) es un término de la psiquiatría o la psicología.